# Wrap code with HTML (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html

I want to add some html to a widget area, basically to wrap the inner content. Here is the current code:

```
<aside id="meta-2" class="widget widget_meta"><h1 class="widget-title">Stuff</h1>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Log in</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Entries <abbr title="Really Simple Syndication">RSS</abbr></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Comments <abbr title="Really Simple Syndication">RSS</abbr></a></li>
  </ul>
</aside>
```

I want it to become:

```
<aside id="meta-2" class="widget widget_meta"><h1 class="widget-title">Stuff</h1>
 <div class="widget-inner">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Log in</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Entries <abbr title="Really Simple Syndication">RSS</abbr></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Comments <abbr title="Really Simple Syndication">RSS</abbr></a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</aside>
```

**Please note** that some 'widgets' don't contain a UL, there might just be an image inside or some text.

I have tried some jQuery snippets using before, append etc but to no avail.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **[.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)**:

```
$( "aside ul" ).wrap( "<div class='widget-inner'></div>" );
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/94019b2d/)**

**Update:** for non uniform DOM:

```
$( "aside h1" ).nextAll().wrap( "<div class='widget-inner'></div>" );
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LqLxueqa/)**

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my question above as I didn't explain it well. Some widgets won't have a UL inside them, some maybe just text or an image for example.

Comment: @HuwRowlands: what about h tag. is it going to be always there??

Comment: Yes, H1 will always be there.

Answer (score 0):

use `.wrap()` function see link : [wrap() jquery](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

Answer (score 0):

Answer from above was:

```
$( "aside h1" ).nextAll().wrap( "<div class='widget-inner'></div>" );
```

Thanks